# Where is my wallpaper stored- Galaxy S20, Android 13

Tags: wallpaper, android-13, samsung-galaxy-s-20

I'm in the process of switching from a Galaxy S20 to a Pixel 7 Pro. Both are running Android 13. I completed the data transfer, but my old wallpaper (a picture I took a long time ago which I really like) didn't transfer. I cannot find it in the wallpaper and style control on either phone, and I've tried looking everywhere in the data folder I can think of when the S20 is connected to my PC.  This is a picture that I believe I had on a Galaxy S8 and it transferred to my Galaxy S20. I'm trading the S20 in and need to get it in the mail soon. I appreciate any help/advice you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

On my Samsung Note it is at

`Android\data\com.samsung.android.wallpaper.res\files`

Comment: Thank you!  I just looked there and there's nothing in the files folder.  I know it must be in the phone somewhere, I'm just stumped.